# How to deal with Chinese in NLTK (python)?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, nltk

Input file has code "utf8 without BOM", each row is like:

```
( IP ( NP ( NP ( NR 上海 ) ( NR 浦东 ) ) ( NP ( NN 开发 ) ( NP ( CC 与 ) ( NP ( NN 法制 ) ( NN 建设 ) ) ) ) ) ( VP ( VV 同步 ) ) )
```

I want to use NLTK to build a tree from this string by using

```
nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring
```

My output is the form of "\u4e0a\u6d77".

How could I convert the output to utf8?

I don't understand why `a`'s output is the form of utf8?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import nltk
tparse = nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
class cal_prob:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def input_dataset(self, path="CTB-auto-pos/"):
        trainfile = open(path+"train.txt", "r+")
        datas = trainfile.read().split("\n")
        for data in datas:
            data = unicode(data) # change them to unicode
            print data
            tree = tparse(data)
            print tree
            print unicode(str(tree)).decode("utf8")
            print unicode(str(tree)).encode("utf8")
            break
        #
        a = u"(IP \n (NP (NP (NR \u4e0a\u6d77) (NR \u6d66\u4e1c)) (NP (NN \u5f00\u53d1) (NP (CC \u4e0e) (NP (NN \u6cd5\u5236) (NN \u5efa\u8bbe))))) (VP (VV \u540c\u6b65)))"
        print a
        print a.decode("utf8")
        trainfile.close()
a = cal_prob()
a.input_dataset()
```

Comment: You are using Python 2. Switching to Python 3 **today** will take care of this problem (or at least 90% of it), and your next 50 problems. It's not worth your trouble to sort out the crazy things that Python 2 does with character encodings, when the current version is so much better.

Comment: And <code>" '\u6d66' ".decode('unicode-escape')</code> is useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example of opening an encoded file properly.  There is no need for the `reload(sys)` trick (See https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/) or other encoding/decoding.

`tree.pformat()` displays the tree as you would like:

```
import nltk
import io

with io.open('train.txt', encoding='utf8') as trainfile:
    for line in trainfile:
        print tree
        print
        print tree.pformat()
```

Output:

```
(IP
  (NP
    (NP (NR \u4e0a\u6d77) (NR \u6d66\u4e1c))
    (NP (NN \u5f00\u53d1) (NP (CC \u4e0e) (NP (NN \u6cd5\u5236) (NN \u5efa\u8bbe)))))
  (VP (VV \u540c\u6b65)))

(IP
  (NP
    (NP (NR 上海) (NR 浦东))
    (NP (NN 开发) (NP (CC 与) (NP (NN 法制) (NN 建设)))))
  (VP (VV 同步)))
```